# AdMob banner issues android

Tags: android, admob

I'd like to place ads in my MainActivity below FrameLayout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</FrameLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

I have added this to my Manifest:
`<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>`

And my build.gradle also looks fine. Here is my java code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(),"ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxx");
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)  // An example device ID
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(request);
```

But when I run the app I can't see the ads and in the LogCat I got this errors:

`W/Ads: Invalid unknown request error: [Cannot determine request type. Is your ad unit id correct?]`

`W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 1`

`W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 1`

I have tried almost everything I found on the web but nothing worked for me. I think maybe the issue is in my activity_main.xml because of the FrameLayout doesn't give enough place to the ads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems fine (although you should call `MobileAds.initialize()` from the `onCreate()` method of your `Application` class, not from an `Activity`).

Looks like the only problem could be the `banner_ad_unit_id` resource being an invalid ad unit ID (as the error message also suggests).